# difference between module and box

Tags: oop, modular

i want to know what is the difference between box and module in programming
i have been asked this question 
and somehow i am confuse now

reading on web and document that what is box in programming
and i found below link
https://www.nbs-system.com/en/blog/black-box-grey-box-white-box-testing-what-differences/

if the box is the top link and similar link then the box is the testing of the 
program and module is the proram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "box" is just a common word from an object you know from real world. It servers as an analogy with code put together to form some kind of software component. This is because it's internal parts are so related to each other, on responsabilities and communication, on internal data use, on overall goal, that it makes sense to group them together. We name it module and many times this maps to a source file (but doesn't have to), but the same grouping concept applies to classes, packages (usually modules/classes grouped together), libraries or even complete applications or systems.

What the box term mostly refers to is the fact that there is a frontier between what is inside the box and actors interacting with it from the outside (users or other systems).

The box has to present a public interface to external world, in order to become usable, or useful. This has to be documented, otherwise you don't know how to use it. When you use it based on this info only to achieve your goals, not knowing anything about the internals, we say you are using a "black box".

This has lots of advantages because it can make the box a powerful abstraction that is simple to use, wrapping a possible complex implementation inside. It encapsulates things and hides them from the user.

If by any means, you as an external actor use the box in some way, because you know how something is done inside, you are violating this encapsulation principle. You are probably entering in "grey box" usage mode. This is dangerous because if the box is changed your assumptions (and code) may fail.

When using it as a "white box" you really know entirely how it is made inside so you can make very well informed decisions in your code, but now the box code can't be touched really. So there goes the abstraction.

When coding, you mostly want to code against black boxes, and want also to build your own black boxes, for abstraction, cohesion, and modularity reasons.

Grey and white boxes make most sense when it comes the time (hopefully from the start) to test the code you have written. Here you still want to test your system as a black box, but want also to use white box testing, because you want both observable behaviour and internal detailed behaviour to be correct.

Grey testing in particular applies probably when you are testing code you have written that uses other modules or libraries you have not, and generally do not want to test (code of others was tested already), but still you have some knowledge about its internals and you make additional tests to cover *your code*, that explore this knowledge.

Edit:
So unless they want you to distinguish the module as the code that's inside, and the box as the wrapping public interface for the module, there's no difference actually.